# Image with position absolute have no width in flex layout

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to build a horizontal carousel and want a 3:4 image aspect ratio for images.

What I am trying to achieve:
[image]
this works if I set `aspect-ratio: 3/4;` property, I can't depend on this property as it isn't widely supported yet.

**Code without maintaining aspect ratio:**

```css
.shorts-carousel.s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.item.s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.short-card.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.short-card.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z a.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.thumbnail.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.image.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="shorts-carousel s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/double-aa-letters-logo-black-swoosh-double-aa-letters-logo-black-swoosh-vector-illustration-letter-180680952.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
</div>
```

**Code where trying to maintain aspect ratio:**

Images doesn't seem to have an width

```css
.shorts-carousel.s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.item.s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.short-card.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.short-card.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z a.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.thumbnail.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 133.3333333333%;
}
.image.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z.s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="shorts-carousel s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/double-aa-letters-logo-black-swoosh-double-aa-letters-logo-black-swoosh-vector-illustration-letter-180680952.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
   <div class="item s-WZNoplQ0Fjd9">
      <div class="short-card s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
         <a href="#" class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
            <div class="thumbnail s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z">
               <picture class="s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail"></picture>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<Card>--> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks you any help!

Comment: If your images height is 300px, then their width should be 225px in order the aspect ration to be 3/4. Then give your '.item' divs height=225px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a new version, that it does what you want, without using the `aspect-ratio`, but it uses "fixed" `width` and `height`. I've done "fixed" height and width, because I saw you were having `300px` as `height` on the main elements.

Here is the code:

```css
* {  margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.shorts-carousel {
  height: 340px; /* for demo purpose only; it should be 300px */ 
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  gap: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden;  
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.thumbnail {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
.image {
  width: 226px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="shorts-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture><img class="image" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/double-aa-letters-logo-black-swoosh-double-aa-letters-logo-black-swoosh-vector-illustration-letter-180680952.jpg" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="short-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <picture class="picture"><img class="image s-jeQbVeYbq5-Z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSy_OgbXEmQB5Pw2B4alMgz-EQbsyuRaBzMIR9bF9ngEEkTY2ydnBQTb6RYwgjY&amp;s=10" alt="thumbnail" crossorigin="anonymous"></picture>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--<Card>--> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If you want to have a "responsive" layout, you can achieve the same result with `rem` instead of `px`, but it will "scale" the `shorts-carousel` element, instead of being "fluid" with the fixed `height` as on the example above.

Comment: hey! yes I tried this but the images doesn't show.

Comment: @jeremy I've made a new version and it's working, but it uses "fixed" `height` and `width`. Still I think you can go for it, unless you want to have a "responsive" layout.

Comment: thanks I had to do it this way.